# What is the first moment of an isosceles right triangle about the vertex of the right angle?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

What is the first moment of an isosceles right triangle about the vertex of the right angle?

I was thinking to look at it as

$$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \int_{0}^{\sec(\theta)} r^2drd\theta.$$

Does that make any sense?

Comment: Can you draw a picture? (having a hard time visualizing it)

Answer (score 1):

Your integral is correct (for an isosceles right triangle with unit altitude and hence unit area), and it seems like a good way to calculate the first moment, since calculating it in Cartesian coordinates is also complicated and involves two non-trivial integrations instead of one.

[Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20sec%5E3%20x%20for%20x=-pi/4..pi/4) finds a nice form for the result:

$$\displaystyle\frac13\left(\sqrt2+2\tanh^{-1}\tan\frac\pi8\right)=\frac13\left(\sqrt2+2\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt2-1\right)\right)\;.$$